# jQuery array random index

Tags: jquery, arrays, random

I have an array in jQuery with 19 fields and would like to alert a random one. I was thinking about some Math.rand()?

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lazy answer for lazy question:

```
alert( arr[(~~(Math.random() * arr.length))] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Math.random` like below,

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* $('selector').length)
//                                                 ^--$('selector').length = 19
```